# How to specify a User-Agent header for grpc-java client?

Tags: grpc, user-agent, grpc-java

I need to specify a `User-Agent` HTTP header for my grpc-java client requests.

I was trying to use a `ClientInterceptor` to specify a `User-Agent` header via Metadata, but my requests `User-Agent` is still a default for grpc which is "grpc-java-okhttp/1.27.2"

Answer (score 3):

One should use a `ChannelBuilder` to specify a `User-Agent` for all client requests

```
  fun getUser(url: String): User {
    val channelBuilder = OkHttpChannelBuilder
      .forTarget(url)
      // specify desired User-Agent here
      .userAgent("YourApp/1.0.0")

    return UserServiceGrpc
      .newStub(channelBuilder.build())
      .withDeadlineAfter(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .getUser()
  }
```

Your resulting `User-Agent` request header would be `YourApp/1.0.0 grpc-java-okhttp/1.27.2`